# Sidekiq job - return fail or success on condition

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sidekiq

How can I programmatically fail a job in Sidekiq?

Calling `system('some_command')` inside a `perform()` function always return a successful job.

I want to fail a job based on a condition like this:

```rb
def perform(data)
  output = system('some_command')
  if output
    # return this job as :success
  else
    # return this job as :fail
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you just raise an exception, it will make the sidekiq job fail :

```
def perform(data)
  output = system('some_command')
  raise StandardError, "my error is so sexy" unless output
end
```

Of course, you should replace the dumb error message I wrote by something meaningful.

NOTE: `unless x` is just the same as `if !x`